# What's is the difference between api and just jar files?

Tags: java

In .gradle/caches/transform-3/... there is `jetified-facebook-login-5.15.3.jar` and `jetified-facebook-login-5.15.3-api.jar`

I'm also assuming `jetified-facebook-login-5.15.3.api.jar` can be imported to a project so that one can use Facebook related api functions in his/her project.

Is the other one just a javapackage an the other javadoc?
Whats the use for each one of them?

Comment: javadoc is just documentation. I think you're mixing concepts up here. and what do you mean "just a javapackage"?

Comment: so neither of them  contains a documention. I just mean the actual library which runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the other one just a javapackage an the other javadoc?

When you see such a separation, then the `-api` is usually just an api definition (interfaces and their refered classes), the *default* jar usually contains a complete implementation.

This is used often when you have some runtime environment providing the implementation.

A clear example is servlet-api.jar and servlet.jar - when creating a web application to run on an application server, you may need the servlet-api to compile and build the web app. But the actual implementation of the servlet infrastructure will be provided by the application server itself.